# Any Benefit To Combining or Splitting Conditions in CASE Statement?

Tags: sql, case, implementation

I have the following CASE statement in my SELECT:

```
CASE
    -- Populated, US or Canadian Formatted and Confirmed; Return Zip Untouched
    WHEN ( ( uc.[Zip] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[Zip] <> '' ) AND EXISTS( SELECT [Zip] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE ( (LEN(uc.[Zip]) = 5 OR LEN(uc.[Zip]) = 10) AND [Zip] = LEFT(uc.[Zip], 5) ) OR ( LEN(uc.[Zip]) = 7 AND [Zip] = uc.[Zip] ) ) )
        THEN uc.[Zip]   -- Data Confirmed, Return Zip Untouched

    -- Populated but not found above; Attempt to determine from City, State, Country
    WHEN ( uc.[Zip] IS NOT NULL OR uc.[Zip] <> '') AND EXISTS( SELECT [Zip] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], NULL, uc.[Country]) )
        THEN ( SELECT [Zip] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], NULL, uc.[Country]) )  -- Match Found; Return Match

    -- Not Populated; Attempt to determine from City, State, Country
    WHEN ( uc.[Zip] IS NULL OR uc.[Zip] = '')  AND EXISTS( SELECT [Zip] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], NULL, uc.[Country]) )
        THEN ( SELECT [Zip] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], NULL, uc.[Country]) )  -- Match Found; Return Match

    -- No Match Found
    ELSE uc.[Zip]
END AS [Zip]
```

The middle two WHEN conditions are ultimately doing the exact same thing.  Is there any benefit to combining or leaving them separate?  I have them separate now just to make it easier to track my thought process

Comment: Tag with the implementation. Since there is a query and/or UDF involved, I suspect that there is no relevant optimizations available or difference, assuming that is the right evaluation order. Those aspects will likely dominate any logic evaluation or branching overhead itself. Being clearer (to ensure being correct) is likely more appropriate.

Comment: That said, `SELECT [Zip] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], uc.[State], NULL, uc.[Country]` seems suspiciously duplicated based on a-ZIP (and the inverse of no-ZIP) as a predicate.

Comment: @user2864740 You lost me on the duplicated/inverse.

Comment: @user2864740 The `fn_LocationInfo` function takes variations of City, State, Zip, Country and returns all of the info.  Ie in the US you can get City, State and Country from a single 5-digit zip code.  The function is a whole lot of ELSEIF with every combination possible for the variables.  I'm about 85% confident that it works as it should, even if it's a bit slow.

Comment: It looks like you should join to `fn_LocationInfo` and eliminate, or at least greatly simplify, the `case`.

Comment: You could well combine them into just one ```WHEN EXISTS ...``` as you're doing the same thing regardless of whether the zip is populated or not. I believe this could only improve performance as the checks will no longer be made, but also it'll make your query more readable.

Comment: And just wanted to add to @Bohemian's comment. This situation might be a good candidate for Postgres' ```LATERAL``` join or SQL Server's ```CROSS APPLY``` join mechanisms, or whatever the equivalent is in the flavor of SQL you're using. They can often improve performance drastically. And as stated your ```CASE``` will simplify considerably.